Time travel debug C# xUnit test
I use xUnit (C#, .NET) for an integration test. It's hard to find why it fails and I want to  use Time Travel debugging.
Unfortunately, I don't see how I can do that with Visual Studio. The test should be run locally.
I tried Windbg to record the test run with Windbg, which has the Time Travel feature. Unfortunately, I couldn't manage to load the CLR symbols in a Time Travel recording. Breakpoints in C# are not hit, the debugger just flies over them.
Is there a way to do time travel debugging for local .NET code?

It looks like that feature is called IntelliTrace step-back in Visual Studio Enterprise.
